# Get all unordered list elements and their text - puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to retrieve an unordered list along with all the elements within it. The `<ul>` has `<li>`'s with cities' names as text and I want to get those cities.

```
await page
      .$eval(
        "body > div.page > div.container.account.cf > div.account-content > div.addressPage > div.addressCard.addAddressCard > div:nth-child(6) > ul",
        (ul) => {
          console.log(ul.innerHTML);
          for (let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
            cityArray.push(ul.children[i].textContent);
          }
        }
      )
      .then((array) => console.log(array))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

When I am trying to use `console.log`, nothing gets printed out.

Answer (score 4):

The `console.log` won't work, because the `pageFunction` is evaluated in the browsers context, so you need to watch for console output in the browser.

As an alternative you can save the inner HTML outside the function an log it then:

```js
const ulHtml = '';

await page.$eval(
    "body > div.page > div.container.account.cf > div.account-content > div.addressPage > div.addressCard.addAddressCard > div:nth-child(6) > ul",
    (ul) => {
        ulHtml = ul.innerHTML;
    }
);
```

About your headline question: `.innerHTML` isn't returning an Array[], so you cant save it in an array like that. To get an array with the text of each `<li>` simply loop over it in the `pageFunction`:

```js
await page.$eval(
    "body > div.page > div.container.account.cf > div.account-content > div.addressPage > div.addressCard.addAddressCard > div:nth-child(6) > ul",
    (ul) => {
        const cityArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
            cityArray.push(ul.children[i].textContent);
        }

        return cityArray;
    }
).then((cityArray) => { console.log(cityArray) });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, this is another question. How do I do something AFTER the city array has been pushed. I have edited the code to show the promise chaining but I get an error saying 'cityArray is not defined'

Comment: When my answer was helpful please mark it with the checkmark on the left side of my answer. To use the array in the next `then` you need to return it. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I accomplished this using a query selector combination with DOM manipulation. This is an old issue, but if someone is looking for an updated solution, just do this:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.container');

  await page.$eval(
    ".ul",
    (ul) => {
      const list = [];

      ul.querySelectorAll(".list-item").forEach((li) => {
        list.push(li.querySelector(".sub-element").innerText);
        // Though, you can use other DOM manipulation methods here:
        // Example: li.querySelector(".sub-element").getAttribute("href"), or something like that.
      });

      return list;
    }
  ).then((list) => { 
    console.log(list);
    // Do whatever you want with your list here...
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('ERR:', err);
  });
```

Hope this helps you to get it working :)